# Universal Windows Platform equivalent for intent-filter in Android

Tags: c#, android, webview, win-universal-app

I am developing a simple *`Universal Windows Platform Page`*. It only contains a `web view`. I would like to be able to open some links with my app. The equivalent in `Android` would be an `intent filter`. Is this possible for `UWP`??.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN - Windows apps concept mapping for Android and iOS developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/android-ios-uwp-map):

> You can register your app to be the default handler for a URI scheme name by registering a protocol in the package manifest and updating the Application.OnActivated event handler, optionally returning results. In the same way you can register your app to be the default handler for certain file types by adding a declaration in the package manifest and handling the Application.OnFileActivated event.

Comment: This is the right way, you are right, but I get this error "no suitable method for override OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)"

Comment: See if [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-launch-an-app-for-results) helps you